# While executing the java code i am getting below error.please help me fixing this

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, jira, alm

**Code:**

```
package demo1;

public class helloworld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Create a new instance of the Firefox driver
                WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

                //Launch the Online Store Website
                driver.get("http://www.store.demoqa.com");

                // Print a Log In message to the screen
                System.out.println("Successfully opened the website www.Store.Demoqa.com");

                //Wait for 5 Sec
                Thread.sleep(5000);
```

**Error**:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    WebDriver cannot be resolved to a type
    FirefoxDriver cannot be resolved to a type

```
at demo1.helloworld.main(helloworld.java:8)
```

Answer (score 0):

Import these two lines :

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
```

Assuming all pre-requisites have already been taken care.

Answer (score 0):

You can use use `selenium-java.x.jar` in your classpath.
Compile and run...